# Merge two lines with grep or sed

Tags: python, regex, windows, sed, grep

I have such a problem: I have two files with keys:

```
file1: aa, bb, cc, dd, ee, ff, gg;

file2: aa, bb, cc, zz, yy, ww, oo;
```

I need to write a script using **grep/sed** to produce two files:

```
res1.txt - will contain similar keys from both files: aa, bb, cc;

res2.txt - will contain ONLY keys from file2 which differs from files1: zz, yy, ww, oo.
```

Can I do it with this tools and how or I need to use python script to do this work? Thanks.

I am using Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python you can do the following.

```
string1 = "aa, bb, cc, dd, ee, ff, gg;"
string2 = "aa, bb, cc, zz, yy, ww, oo;"

list1 = string1.rstrip(';').split(', ')
list2 = string2.rstrip(';').split(', ')

common_words = filter(lambda x: x in list1, list2)
unique_words = filter(lambda x: x not in list1, list2)

>>> common_words
['aa', 'bb', 'cc']
>>> unique_words
['zz', 'yy', 'ww', 'oo']
```

You can then write these to a file if you want.

E.g.:

```
common_string = ', '.join(common_words) + ';'
with open("common.txt", 'w') as common_file:
    common_file.write(common_string)
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `comm` to show common lines, but you have to sort the files (and convert them to the *key per line* format through `tr`):

```
comm -12 <(tr -s ' ,' '\n' < file1 | sort) <(tr -s ' ,' '\n' < file2 | sort)
comm -13 <(tr -s ' ,' '\n' < file1 | sort) <(tr -s ' ,' '\n' < file2 | sort)
```

Comment: what is comm? i'm on windows pc

Comment: @yozhik - it would be useful to mention that your on windows in your question. When you name 2 traditionally UNIX tools in your desired solution, it's reasonable for us to assume you're on UNIX.

Answer (score 3):

Ugly job for GNU [sed](/questions/tagged/sed):

```
sed -r 's#(\w+)[,;]\s*#/\1/{x;s/.*/\&\1,/;x};#g;s#.*#&x;s/,$/;/#' file1|sed -rf - file2 > res1.txt
sed -r 's#(\w+),\s#\1[,;]\\s*|#g;s#(.*);#s/\1//g#' file1|sed -rf - file2 > res2.txt
```

---

```
$ cat file1 file2
aa, bb, cc, dd, ee, ff, gg;
aa, bb, cc, zz, yy, ww, oo;

$ sed -r 's#(\w+)[,;]\s*#/\1/{x;s/.*/\&\1,/;x};#g;s#.*#&x;s/,$/;/#' file1|sed -rf - file2
aa,bb,cc;

$ sed -r 's#(\w+),\s#\1[,;]\\s*|#g;s#(.*);#s/\1//g#' file1|sed -rf - file2
zz, yy, ww, oo;
```

---

Quoting for `Windows`:

```
sed -r "s#(\w+)[,;]\s*#/\1/{x;s/.*/\&\1,/;x};#g;s#.*#&x;s/,$/;/#" file1|sed -rf - file2 > res1.txt
sed -r "s#(\w+),\s#\1[,;]\\s*|#g;s#(.*);#s/\1//g#" file1|sed -rf - file2 > res2.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

The general purpose text processing tool that comes with every UNIX installation is named `awk`:

```
awk -F', *|;' '
NR==FNR { for (i=1; i<NF;i++) file1[$i]; next }
{
    for (i=1; i<NF; i++) {
        sfx = ($i in file1 ? 1 : 2)
        printf "%s%s", sep[sfx], $i > ("res" sfx ".txt")
        sep[sfx]=", "
    }
}
END { for (sfx in sep) print ";" > ("res" sfx ".txt") }
' file1 file2
```